# Travelling to Lisbon by bus in July

Tags: europe, buses, belgium, lisbon

This summer I would like to visit Lisbon from Belgium.
I would like to avoid using any planes, or driving myself. Preferably I would like to take a coach (like FlixBus).

However, I've searched on several websites of bus / coach companies and no bus seems to go from Belgium to Portugal during the holiday season.

Are there any companies I've might have missed who operate on this route this time of year?

Comment: Is the train out of the question?  For long-distance European travel where I want to avoid driving and flying, I find the trains are usually excellent.

Answer (score 3):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Brussels/Lisbon) tells us that [Eurolines](https://www.eurolines.eu) offers this route (I started in Brussels) with a single connection:

[image: 32 hour bus ride]

Unfortunately, that's a 32-hour journey (it's over 19 if you drive straight through without stopping). You might prefer to break it up, working your way through France and Spain by train or bus. There's direct Flixbus service from Madrid to Lisbon, for example. None of these options are likely to compare favorably in cost to flying though.

Answer (score 3):

For information on train options, [The Man in Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/Portugal.htm) website
 is aimed at travel from London, but the route will be similar from Brussels (replacing Eurostar London-Paris with Thalys Brussels-Paris).

e.g.

```
Brussels 10:13 - 11:35 Paris Nord (from €29)
Paris Gare Montparnasse 12:52 - 17:35 Hendaye (from €25)
Irun 18:45 - 07:20 Lisbon (from €27)
```

The total (one-way) cost could be less than €100 if you book well in advance.